# Inner product of k-covariant-tensors and inner product of k-forms

Tags: tensor-calculus

Imagine we have a vector space equipped with a metric tensor with components $g_{a b}$ in some particular basis, and let $\{f^1,...,f^D\}$ be the associated dual basis.

The inner product of vectors can be extended to other objects. For example for $k$-covariant tensors we can define a bilinear product that acts on the basis:

$$ \langle f^{a_1} \otimes ... \otimes f^{a_k}, f^{b_1} \otimes ...\otimes f^{b_k}\rangle = \langle f^{a_1}, f^{b_1} \rangle ...\langle f^{a_k}, f^{b_k} \rangle =g^{a_1 b_1}...g^{a_k b_k}$$
(*)

The point is that I wanted to see the result over $k$-forms. So, using

$$ f^{a_1}\wedge...\wedge f^{a_k} = k! f^{[a_1} \otimes ... \otimes f^{a_k]}$$
(**)

one can compute:

$$ \begin{align} 
\langle f^{a_1}\wedge...\wedge f^{a_k},\, f^{b_1}\wedge...\wedge f^{b_k}\rangle
 & = k!k!\langle  f^{[a_1}\otimes...\otimes f^{a_k]},\, f^{[b_1}\otimes...\otimes f^{b_k]}\rangle \\   
& =k!k! \delta_{c_1}^{[a_1}...\delta_{c_k}^{a_k]} \delta_{d_1}^{[b_1}...\delta_{d_k}^{b_k]} \langle  f^{c_1}\otimes...\otimes f^{c_k},\, f^{d_1}\otimes...\otimes f^{d_k}\rangle   \\
& =k!k! \delta_{c_1}^{[a_1}...\delta_{c_k}^{a_k]} \delta_{d_1}^{[b_1}...\delta_{d_k}^{b_k]}g^{c_1 d_1}...g^{c_k d_k}  \\
!& =k!k! \delta_{c_1}^{[a_1}...\delta_{c_k}^{a_k]} \delta_{d_1}^{b_1}...\delta_{d_k}^{b_k}g^{c_1 d_1}...g^{c_k d_k}  \\
& =k!k! \delta_{c_1}^{[a_1}...\delta_{c_k}^{a_k]}g^{c_1 b_1}...g^{c_k b_k} \\
& =k!~ det (g^{a_i b_j})
\end{align} 
$$
In ! I have absorbed the antisymmetrization of b's because it is induced by the a's one (due to the symmetry of the metric).

However in the literature this is always defined without the k! factor. I have revised the calculations many times and I cannot see any mistake; and, if there are not, the problem arises from the definitions (*) and (**), but both definitions are the typical ones in the context of physics.

Can anyone clarify if this is just a matter of convention or something like this?  (For example that the usual (literature) inner product of $k$-forms is not the one of $k$-covariant tensors particularized). Thanks!

Comment: I do not understanf well how is  $f^{[a_1}\otimes \cdots \otimes f^{a_n]}$ defined. For instance $f^{[i}\otimes f^{j]} = f^i \otimes f^j - f^j \otimes f^i$ or  $= \frac{1}{2!} (f^i \otimes f^j - f^j \otimes f^i)$ ?

Comment: The factor $1/n!$ in the definition of $\wedge$ is necessary if you want that $\wedge$ is associative...otherwise it is matter of convention.

Comment: @ValterMoretti the second one; with the factor 1/2! With this definition you have, for example $dx \wedge dy = dx\otimes dy - dy\otimes dx $.

Comment: Without facotrials  the definition of $\wedge$ is not associative... $a\wedge (b \wedge c) \neq (a\wedge b) \wedge c$. The factorials implies associativity instead... However with factorials the determinant formula you discuss turns out to be less elegant...

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know the detail of the non-associativity, I will think about that.